# How to combine all data from multiple excel sheets per SubjectID in R (or excel)

Tags: r, excel, dataset

I have an Excel file (xlsx) which contains multiple datasheets.
All sheats contain answers to different questionnaires answered by different subjects.
Every Subject has it's on row in each sheet (with SubjectID) and the top row has the unique name of the specific question 
Not all subjects have answered each questionnaire so not all datasheets have the exact same number of rows and the sheets are not ordered by subjectID

I want to create 1 file in which each subject has it's own row and all answers from that subject are added to that row. In case a subject has not answered a specific question (or does not appear in a sheet at all, their value for that column should remain empty.

I can't seem to find a way to combine all these steps (either in R of Excel)

Anyone who can help me get going?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without a specific example, but the following *might* work:

```
library(readxl) 
lapply(excel_sheets(path), read_excel, path = path) %>%
purrr::reduce(merge,by="subjectID")
```

`path` is the path to the Excel file.

This creates a list with each sheet as one data.frame within it, and feeds it into 'reduce' which merges the first two dataframes by subjectID, and then merges the result with the third and so on.

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful to really answer the question.

You can probably accomplish this in R using the tidyverse package:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library("tidyverse")
```

Then you need to import your Excel sheets:

```
Sheet_A <- read_excel(File_Name, sheet = "Sheet_Name")
Sheet_B <- read_excel(File_Name, sheet = "Sheet_Name")
Sheet_Z <- read_excel(File_Name, sheet = "Sheet_Name")
```

Then you need to join all of the sheets on whatever your ID column is called:

```
Come_Together <- Sheet_A %>%
    left_join(Sheet_B, by='ID_COLUMN') %>%
    left_join(Sheet_C, by='ID_COLUMN')
```

And then you can write them out to an Excel file in one sheet, if you'd like:

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library("xlsx")
write.xlsx(Come_Together, filepath, sheetName = "Sheet_Name")
```